# How to integrate history.js to my ajax site?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, history.js

I have left and right div in my website and with navigation buttons.
Let's say button_1, button_2.

When clicking on these button will change the right div content using ajax so means the left div do nothing.

The above is what I have done but I have a problem here, the url doesn't change. And I found history.js is able to solve this issue but I cannot find any tutorial about history.js + ajax.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank in adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read here: [This gist will ajaxify your website with the HTML5 History API using History.js and ScrollTo.](https://gist.github.com/854622)